# Pandas .loc method won't return empty dataframe when checking for equality

Tags: python, pandas

I have created a calculated column of dtype `float64`, and preset precision 2 decimal places.

`data['Engine Efficiency'] = 4.0 * data['Engine Displacement'] / (data['# Cylinders'].astype('float64') * 3.24)`

I am trying to filter this column based on its value, checking for equality:
`data.loc[data['Engine Efficiency'] == 0.62]`

Also tried the following in case of broken float math:

`data[np.isclose(data['Engine Efficiency'], 0.62)]`

`data[np.abs(data['Engine Efficiency'] - float(0.62)) < 0.0001*float(0.62)]`

In all cases, the output is an empty dataframe, which shouldn't be the case.

When checking for the inequality I get back the full dataframe, essentially meaning that the values I am searching don't exist. This should be a numeric issue I suppose during the calculation.

I have tried changing the calculation formula, using `math.pi` / `np.pi`, setting precision, converting everything to float and still nothing.

You can find the dataset and notebook files here, if needed:
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/aa57abd8d2626e1ec39a0f32ecf59cad20230225114538/184585

Answer (score 1):

The `isclose` code will work if the values are correct. Your problem is that there **really** are no rows with `Engine Efficiency` of 0.62 or close to it (using default tolerance). This is not clear in your output because of the display format. To see what is happening use

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:03.5f}'.format
data.loc[(data['Engine Efficiency']> 0.61) & (data['Engine Efficiency']< 0.63)]
```

and you will see the values is actually 0.62633 using my display format. You could round values using:

```
data['Engine Efficiency'] = round(data['Engine Efficiency'],2)
```

when that value would be 0.63000

Comment: I found another way to get around it, similar to your format, but applying the map function. The value 0.62 existed in one of my tries, I may had changed the code before uploading it.

Comment: It was your code `pd.options.display.precision = 2` which was at the root of the issue  by obscuring actual values which of course can matter in comparisons; display precision not meaning changing the actual value.

Comment: Yeah, I realised it after too when saving to csv and opening with Excel. Thank you for noticing!